# Merging data frames in R, in specific order

Tags: r

I'm still very new to manipulating data in R and have run into a seemingly simple problem that i can't figure out how to solve.

I have 3 data frames each with 9 columns and 720 rows.

I need to merg them into one data frame with 9 columns and (3x720) rows, where  the first 3 rows in the final data frame is the first rows of each of the original data frames, and so forth for all rows in the original data frames.

name of the dataframes

alt1

alt2

alt3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new column in the data frames for the row number, then you merge them with a `rbind` and you order them based on the `rn` column that represents the row number in the original data frames. Note that the `rbind` will work only if the data frames have the same column names.

```
alt1 $rn <- seq.int(nrow(alt1))
alt2$rn <- seq.int(nrow(alt2))
alt3$rn <- seq.int(nrow(alt3))

df <- rbind(alt1, alt2, alt3)
df[order(df$rn),]
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi Barbara, Thank you very much for the help! feel stupid that I didn't think of simply sorting the data after merging.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the columns names are the same in all 3 datasets.

```
# create example dataset
set.seed(1)

alt1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(4),
                  y = rnorm(4))

alt2 = data.frame(x = rnorm(4),
                  y = rnorm(4))

alt3 = data.frame(x = rnorm(4),
                  y = rnorm(4))

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


c("alt1", "alt2", "alt3") %>%                                        # get names of datasets                
  map_df(function(x) {d = get(x); d$row_index = 1:nrow(d); d}) %>%   # for each name: get data, add a column with the name and bind them all
  arrange(row_index)                                                 # order by row index

#              x           y row_index
# 1  -0.62645381  0.32950777         1
# 2   0.57578135 -0.62124058         1
# 3  -0.01619026  0.91897737         1
# 4   0.18364332 -0.82046838         2
# 5  -0.30538839 -2.21469989         2
# 6   0.94383621  0.78213630         2
# 7  -0.83562861  0.48742905         3
# 8   1.51178117  1.12493092         3
# 9   0.82122120  0.07456498         3
# 10  1.59528080  0.73832471         4
# 11  0.38984324 -0.04493361         4
# 12  0.59390132 -1.98935170         4
```

This is to double check that you get the first row of each dataset on top. You can remove the unnecessary columns with `%>% select(-row_index)` in the end.

If you have ONLY those 3 datasets loaded in your workspace you can replace the first line `c("alt1", "alt2", "alt3")` with `ls()` to get a fully automated solution.